# linux command that would be used to change the file permissions to reflect the following permission set

Tags: linux, command

What's the command to do the following:?

- All users can read the file

  No-one but the owner can write to the file

  The owner should have all permissions granted

Chmod 704 is this correct?
rwx---r--

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to calculate these is to add them up from the following form:

```
421421421 - So you just add the positions you need, for example
rwx---r-- - You delete the numbers where you have no permissions and you get
421---4-- - Now you just sum them in groups of three
 7  0  4  - And this is your permission
```

After a while you'll be able to do these in your head very easily.

And now you apply to a single file:

```
chmod 704 filename
```

Or recursively to all:

```
chmod -R 704 *
```

Or selectively:

```
find . -iname '*.phpsh' -exec chmod 704 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't remember the octal codes, use the symbolic mode:

```
chmod u+rwx,g-rwx,o-wx,o+r file
```

It reads as *"user can read write execute, group can't read write execute, others can't write execute, others can read"*.